# functions not working on dataset of subset within a subset

Tags: r, function, dataset, subset, mean

In R I am attempting to test the mean number of children someone with college education vs someone without college education has from the US census. However I learned there was a heavy skew in the data from age so I meant to restrict age to over 18. However once I would restrict both age and college education level functions would stop working on the data-set (the data set created looks normal). The functions still don't work but I have gotten closer by making the 18> a variable

`eighteen<-ACS_2016_CO$NCHILD[ACS_2016_CO$AGE>17]`

`eighteen[ACS_2016_CO$EDUCD>6]`

gives numeric data

`eighteen[ACS_2016_CO$EDUCD<7]`

gives numeric data

`mean(eighteen[ACS_2016_CO$EDUCD<7])`

gives N/A

I have tried with sum and length to attempt to cheese it but both functions too give N/A. Is there a quicker way to restrict both the age and education level at once or does anyone know the reason N/A keeps showing up? Thank-You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eighteen` is a subset of `ACS_2016_CO` and has different length than `ACS_2016_CO$EDUCD`. You could include both the condition and take `mean` of them by doing

```
mean(with(ACS_2016_CO,NCHILD[AGE > 17 & EDUCD < 7]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yep that works! Thank you so much spent last 2 hours trying to figure it out and just made an account for this question. Have a good day!